# How to format the output in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, formatting, printf

I have an 1D array of length equals 52, and it consists of random integer values. I want to print out the array with indices using uppercase and lowercase alphabet. 
For example,

```
index:    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T
array:   -1 -1 -1 -1 32 -1 -1 -1 -1 12 -1 -1 -1 -1 20 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
index:    U  V  W  X  Y  Z  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i   ...  x  y  z
array:   -1 -1 -1 -1 15 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1   ... -1 -1 -1
```

I tried with a `for` loop to `printf("%c\t\r%d\t\b", 'A', -1)`, but \b didn't move the cursor up. Instead of generating the format I wanted (showed above), I got something like below,

```
 A
-1   B
-1   C
-1   .
 .   .
 .   .
 .
```

Anyone knows how to generate the format showed above?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Print `"index: A B ... T"` and then `"array: -1 -1 ... -1"` etc

Comment: I don't think that will print out the format I want when the length of the arrays exceed one screen length. It will just print out index array first, and then print out the content array.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am giving you only the Example of format which you want with C Language Program compiled in turbo C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int j=96;
    clrscr();
    for(int i=1;i<=52;i+=2)
    {
        gotoxy(i,1);
        printf("%c",j+=1);

        gotoxy(i,2);
        printf("%d ",random(2));
    }
    j=96;
    for(i=1;i<=52;i+=2)
    {
        gotoxy(i,3);
        printf("%c",j+=1);

        gotoxy(i,4);
        printf("%d ",random(2));
    }

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does not depending on ASCII and is quite portable.

Simply look up the index display character in another array.

```
static const char index[52] = 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int A[52] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, 32, -1, -1, -1, -1, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, 20, -1 ...};

int i;
fputs("index:  ", stdout);
for (i=0; i<52; i) {
  printf("  %c", index[i]);
}
fputs("\n", stdout);

fputs("array:  ", stdout);
for (i=0; i<52; i) {
  printf(" %2d", A[i]);
}
fputs("\n", stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the code doesn't print out the exact form I want. When the output exceeds one screen length, the code will print out the index array first, and then print out array A. I need something that can print out index array and A array simultaneously, so that both array can change to new line at the same time.

Comment: @Steve  Suggest amending your post to clearly state the screen length requirements including screen min, max and type of output system. The answer is system specific.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ does not have any notion of a screen or console, they only see streams of bytes, which have no inherent display characteristics. There are third-party APIs like [ncuses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) to help you do that.

One way, Using ANSI escape sequence for [cursor movement](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html), where ESC[y;xH moves curser to row y, col x, where top left corner is {1,1}.

```
printf("\033[%d;%dH", row, col);
```

In windows you can try,

Use SetConsoleCursorPosition. [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx)

There are a bunch of other functions in the same part of the MSDN library. Some of them may be useful too.

Otherwise, you can restrict the printing to be a particular amount of index for a line, below code you can try.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    const char charIndex[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const unsigned int counter = 133;
    const unsigned int hBuffer = 14; // max number of indexes in a line

    unsigned int row,j;
    unsigned int arrIndex = 0,yetToPrintcount = counter,htempBuffer;

    // Nof of Rows needed to print the counter
    unsigned int noOfRows = ( counter / hBuffer );
    // if no reminder means no trailing values less than hBuffer to print
    if ( counter % hBuffer == 0 ) noOfRows--;

    srand(time(NULL)); // For random numbers

    for ( row = 0 ; row <= noOfRows; ++row)
    {

        // For printing the trailing numbers
        // which are less than the h_buffer size
        if ( yetToPrintcount < hBuffer ) 
            htempBuffer = yetToPrintcount;
        else 
            htempBuffer = hBuffer;

        // printing the index first
        printf("index:  ");
        for (j = 0; j < htempBuffer; ++j){
            // circular printing of index
            if( arrIndex == (sizeof(charIndex) / sizeof(char))-1 ) arrIndex = 0;
            printf("  %c", charIndex[arrIndex++]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        // printing the array random values
        printf("array:  ");
        for (j = 0; j < htempBuffer; ++j) 
            printf("  %d", rand()%10); // Prints Random numbers between 0 to 9
        printf("\n");

        yetToPrintcount -= hBuffer;
    }

    return 0;

}
```